# Image positioning that leaves a large blank

Tags: includegraphics

In my document, I add an image (almost the width of the page) using `\includegraphics`.

The problem is that the text placed after appears after a large blank as shown in the following screenshot:

My code:

```
Pour les sceptiques, l’image suivante montre la reconstruction « pas à pas » d’un signal créneau : bleu (signal de fréquence $f_1$), orange (fréquences $f_1$ et $3\cdot f_1$), vert (fréquences $f_1$, $3 \cdot f_1$ et $5 \cdot f_1$), rouge (fréquences $f_1$ $\cdots$ $13 \cdot f_1$), orange (fréquences $f_1$, $\cdots$ $59 \cdot f_1$)

\includegraphics[width=180mm, valign=c]{recomposition_creneau}

La décomposition en série de Fourier explique notamment le fait qu’une même note, jouée par différents instruments, sonne différemment bien que leur fréquence fondamentale soit identique. En fait, l’oreille décompose le son complexe (plusieurs fréquences) en sons purs (une seule fréquence) comme on le fait lorsqu’on trace le spectre d’un signal : le cerveau compare puis interprète ce « spectre » ce qui nous permet de reconnaître l’instrument joué (et la fréquence fondamentale pour les mélomanes!).
```

Thanks for your help
[image: positionnement_image]

adding `\fbox{} around the picture gives me :
[image: ajout_fobx]

Comment: The problem is more likely due to what is on the next page , such as another larger unbreakable box.

Comment: Put \fbox{} around the graphic to checks its bounding box.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I updated with the new image

Comment: looks rather odd, but probably your image has large white space.

Comment: PLease, provide an MWE, which reproduce your problem and show frame around image (i.e.  with `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=180mm, valign=c]{recomposition_creneau}}` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were right: the image was taking up a lot of space, I didn't see that the source image file left blank.
By correcting it, I no longer have the problem: thanks